# How to securely store sensitive data on a shared-hosting provider while accessible to server-side scripts?

Tags: database, security

I want to store some sensitive data on my hosting provider which is a shared-hosting, lets say for example on MySQL, and i want it to be accessible to the website(server-side languages like PHP) hosted on same provider, how do i do that?

you see i can't use digest algorithms(MD5, SHA1, etc) beacause i want to restore data back to use them in code,

and

I can't use something like Public-Private Key because i have to store both keys on server, so it would be shared with hosting provider.

any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at PCI-DSS standards?

Comment: no @DeerHunter because it's not just credit card numbers, that was an example & data is not stored on a private hosted servers

Comment: Deer Hunter's advice is good; an existing set of guidelines for storing and processing financially-sensitive data is an excellent place to start for thinking about how you might best store and process your sensitive data.  Sure, your needs will be slightly different, so you won't be able to use PCI-DSS (which has its flaws anyway) as an off-the-shelf cookie-cutter, but it's a sensible place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially at the mercy of the security controls put in place by the hosting provider, so your options are really limited, almost non-existent, if you don't trust said controls.

My advice would be to get a micro reserved instance on Amazon EC2 as I'm assuming performance isn't high on your list if you're using a shared hosting provider.